# How to use sql statement to get the disk storage information in CnosDB?

Tags: cnosdb

I follow the cnosdb document using the following statement:

```sql
select * from usage_schmea.disk_storage;
```

I hope get result, but it's not working:

```
db1 ❯ select * from usage_schmea.disk_storage;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"010001","error_message":"Datafusion: Error during planning: Table not found, tenant: cnosdb db: usage_schmea, table: disk_storage"}
```

I am a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

CnosDB (Cassandra NoSQL Database) is a NoSQL database system, and it doesn't use SQL statements like traditional relational databases. Instead, it uses its own query language for data manipulation and retrieval. However, if you're looking for information about disk storage in CnosDB, you typically interact with the database using its command-line interface or API.

Here's a general guide on how you might retrieve disk storage information from CnosDB:

1. **Connect to the Cluster:** Use the appropriate method to connect to your CnosDB cluster, such as the command-line interface or a programming language-specific API.
2. **Query for Storage Information:** You would need to use the specific commands or API calls provided by CnosDB to retrieve storage-related information. This might include commands to get information about keyspaces, tables, column families, or nodes.

   For example, in CnosDB's CLI, you might run a command like:

   ```bash
   cqlsh> DESCRIBE KEYSPACES;
   ```

   Or, if you're using a programming language and an appropriate CnosDB driver, you might use code like:

   ```py
   from cassandra.cluster import Cluster

   cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'])  # Replace with your node's IP address
   session = cluster.connect()

   rows = session.execute("SELECT keyspace_name, table_name FROM system_schema.tables;")
   for row in rows:
       print(row.keyspace_name, row.table_name)
   ```
3. **Analyze the Results:** Once you have retrieved the necessary information, you can analyze it to understand the disk storage usage, allocation, or other related details.

Remember that CnosDB is designed to handle large volumes of data distributed across nodes, so storage-related queries may be more complex and involve querying system tables, status information, or other relevant sources.

Please refer to CnosDB's official documentation or guides for specific commands and API details related to disk storage information, as the exact methods and syntax might vary depending on the version and setup of your CnosDB cluster.

Answer (score 0):

```
usage_schema ❯ show tables;
+--------------------+
| table_name         |
+--------------------+
| coord_data_in      |
| coord_data_out     |
| http_data_out      |
| sql_data_in        |
| user_queries       |
| vnode_cache_size   |
| vnode_disk_storage |
+--------------------+
```

version 2.3.2.
I think it should be a version issue. The table name in the document should correspond to the old version. In the new version, the disk storage of vnode is stored in vnode_disk_storage, and there is only this related table under usage_schema. Hope to help you.